# Plotting (some values) from a series based on formulas

Tags: excel, macos, datetime, graph, charts

I'm banging my head with a problem that I'm sure has to have a better solution.

I have a data set in Excel[**] imported from some logs that looks like this:

`TIMESTAMP            | OP. TYPE    | Latency
---------------------|-------------|-------
16/10/15 00:08:58,520|      OP1    |276
16/10/15 00:08:58,538|      OP2    |351
16/10/15 00:09:22,371|      OP3    |413
16/10/15 00:09:22,392|      OP2    |463
16/10/15 00:12:09,426|      OP3    |313
16/10/15 00:12:09,447|      OP3    |362
16/10/15 00:15:59,346|      OP1    |243
16/10/15 00:15:59,372|      OP2    |297
16/10/15 00:21:46,056|      OP3    |226
16/10/15 00:21:46,076|      OP1    |274
16/10/15 00:25:32,019|      OP2    |306`

I want to create a scatterplot using the timestamps as series X, and a different "Series" for each of the `Latency` according to the OP type.

I can get a scatter of all the latency points and the timestamps, but I'm struggling to define the series limited to the OP Types. I've tried using array formulas as that works for other calculations.

For example, `{=MAX(IF($B:$B='OP1';$C:$C))}`gives me the max of the series for OP1. But I've tried using `{=IF($B:$B='OP1';$C:$C)}` (which I kind-of expect to return an array with the values of the latency for the OP1) in the Chart Series Y field, and I get an error.

I've got a (clunky/ugly) approach that seems to be able to work in creating a new column for each "OP type", selecting the whole column, and using '{=IF(B:B='OP1';C:C;"")}` as formula. I get a column with empty values where OP. Type is not 1, and the value when it's OP1...

But that looks ugly and I have the feeling there has to be a "better way"...

So any tips more than appreciated.

[**]: Excel 2011 on OSX, in case that matters.. and yes, I'm not very proficient at Excel as you can imagine :-)

Comment: That is **exactly** what I want; how do you get there?  Thanks!

Comment: As for SuperUser vs Stack Overflow, when searching for the topics I've been looking at (formula arrays in charts; conditional series in graphs, and many others) I've seen quite a number of SO question, not so many (quite few) in SU - that's what's made me ask here

Answer (score 0):

I would just sort the table on the OP field and identify the separate data ranges "by hand".